# Let users create elements that only they can see in Firebase (in React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I recently started learning firebase and i find it great. I was able to let users register/login with email and password and once they are on the app they can create "Cards" with some data. However any user that creates an account on my app can then view and delete, edit, etc. any Card created by any user.

My question is simply how can i only display Cards strictly to the users who created them only?

Here is my code up to now:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const cardRef = firebase.database().ref('Cards')
    cardRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const cards = snapshot.val()
      const cardslist = []
      for (let id in cards) {
        cardslist.push({id, ...cards[id] })
      }
      setCardslist(cardslist)
    })
  },[])

//in my jsx i then have cardslist which displays the cards
<div>{cardslist}</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like you haven't made an attempt at this problem yet.  I suggest doing so, and sharing the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I kinda did make a few attempts but none made any sense. I mean i have no idea how to even approach this. Some help would really be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to associate each card with the user who created it, and then use a query for that. See the documentation on ordering and filtering data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: thanks your answer made it work nicely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

1 - Make sure every "card" document has a "creator" field, so you can filter the query with something like...

```
your_query().where("creator", "==", current_viewer_id)
```

2 - Make sure you use Firestore Rules, to limit read/write operations on a card to only the creator of the card. Your use case is one of the first examples you'll see in Firestore Rules documentation and explainer videos.

Good luck! You're almost there.

Comment: Your answer shows the query syntax for Cloud Firestore, while OP is using Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and have a different API for querying data.